# Как преобразовать столбцы в строки в Pandas (UNPIVOT)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть структура данных:

```
id | data1 | data2 | data3
---------------------------
 1 | 's11' | 's12' | 's13'
 2 | 's21' | 's22' | 's23'
 3 | 's31' | 's32' | 's33'
```

Из него хочется получить такой набор:

```
id | data 
----------
 1 | 's11'
 1 | 's12'
 1 | 's13'
 2 | 's21'
 2 | 's22'
 2 | 's23'
 3 | 's31'
 3 | 's32'
 3 | 's33'
```

Я попробовал так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [1, 2, 3], "data1": ['s11', 's22', 's33'], "data2": ["s21", 's22', 's23'],
     'data3': ['s31', 's32', 's33']})
df2 = pd.concat([df[['id', 'data1']], df[['id', 'data2']], df[['id', 'data3']]], keys=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'])
```

Что дает такой набор:

```
     data1 data2 data3  id
--------------------------
d1 0   s11   NaN   NaN   1
   1   s22   NaN   NaN   2
   2   s33   NaN   NaN   3
d2 0   NaN   s21   NaN   1
   1   NaN   s22   NaN   2
   2   NaN   s23   NaN   3
d3 0   NaN   NaN   s31   1
   1   NaN   NaN   s32   2
   2   NaN   NaN   s33   3
```

И собирался дальше сгруппировать

```
df3 = df2.fillna('zzz').groupby('id').first()
```

Результат:

```
   data1 data2 data3
id                  
1    s11   zzz   zzz
2    s22   zzz   zzz
3    s33   zzz   zzz
```

В общем, у меня не вышло, так как группировка схлопнула мои строки по ключу.
Кажется, я могу наплодить еще больше DataFrame переименовав колонки в одинаковые и сделать `concat`, однако мне кажется, что должен быть путь проще. 
Как можно решить мою задачу?

Я так же смотрел в сторону `pivot_table`, но не смог ничего добиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   id data1 data2 data3
0   1   s11   s12   s13
1   2   s21   s22   s23
2   3   s31   s32   s33
```

Решение

```
In [44]: df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index(name='data').drop('level_1',axis='columns')
Out[44]:
   id data
0   1  s11
1   1  s12
2   1  s13
3   2  s21
4   2  s22
5   2  s23
6   3  s31
7   3  s32
8   3  s33
```